# Extracting Data from a Matplotlib Bar Graph Which is Produced by "SHAP" module

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Problem Summary:

1. I am trying to extract data from a Matplotlib Bar Graph. I know this entails using Matplotlib's gca function, but, the [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=extract%20data%20from%20a%20matplotlib%20figure%20to%20a%20pandas%20dataframe%20site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk00O5NULIVg424VMeSzJbT8GxDPcBQ:1595659994793&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip26_Z6OfqAhWUsnEKHV4PDYwQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1366&bih=576) I have tried thus far have failed.
2. The figure is produced automatically by the Python machine learning model interpretability module called "Shap". For More details, see: https://github.com/slundberg/shap
3. After I have extracted the data, I would like to present it as a Pandas Dataframe.

Here is what I have done.

I have a binary classification and model interpretability pipeline which is structured as follows:

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight='balanced', criterion='gini', max_depth=100, 
                                max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=10, min_impurity_decrease=0.0, 
                                min_impurity_split=None, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                                min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2,
                                oob_score=False, random_state=0, verbose=1, warm_start=False)


forest.fit(x_train, y_train)
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(forest)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_train)

figure = plt.figure()
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, features=x_train, feature_names=x_train.columns, plot_type="bar")
```

[image: the figure]

The code works perfectly.

I am trying to extract data from the bar graph, "figure". As you can tell from the "figure = plt.figure()", it is a Matplotlib graph, not the default JS graph that is produced by the package.

Once I have the data, I aim to present it in a dataframe with two columns: "Feature", "Shapely_Value". What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation:
"where the global importance of each feature is taken to be the mean absolute value for that feature over all the given samples."

Which means:
bars_value = `np.abs(shap_values).mean(axis=0)`

Answer (score 3):

You could extract the labels of the yticks and the widths of the rectangular patches:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
tick_labels = ['hydrogen', 'helium', 'lithium', 'beryllium', 'boron', 'carbon', 'nitrogen', 'oxygen', 'fluorine', 'neon']
plt.barh(tick_labels, 1.4 ** (np.arange(len(tick_labels))) / 10)
fig.canvas.draw()

ax = plt.gca()

labels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]
values = [rect.get_width() for rect in ax.patches]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Labels': labels, 'Values': values})
```

[image: plot]

```
      Labels    Values
0   hydrogen  0.100000
1     helium  0.140000
2    lithium  0.196000
3  beryllium  0.274400
4      boron  0.384160
5     carbon  0.537824
6   nitrogen  0.752954
7     oxygen  1.054135
8   fluorine  1.475789
9       neon  2.066105
```

Comment: Overkill but I like it.

Comment: Getting a TypeError.     28     labels = [l.get_text() for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]
     29     values = [rect.get_width() for rect in ax.patches]
---> 30     df = pd.DataFrame({labels, values})
     31 
     32     return df

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Why not `pd.DataFrame({'Feature': labels, 'Shapely_Value': values})`?  `pd.DataFrame` needs a dictionary, while `{labels, values}` is just a set.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extracting data from the figure, do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': x_train.columns, 'Shapely_Value': shap_values})
```

Comment: To clarify a point, the shap_values object is a list with a length of two; I presume it is comprised of one item for each class. Within each list are shapely values for each example in the data. So, the dataframe creation method you suggested won't work in this particular instance.